# OpenCV: Memory leak when writing video from webcam using cvWriteFrame

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I want to record video from webcam using opencv.

I put the following code inside a timer event handler function, which is called each 50 ms

```
IplImage *image = cvQueryFrame(camera);
IplImage *resizeImage = cvCreateImage( size, 8, 3);
cvResize(image, resizeImage);
cvWriteFrame(writer, resizeImage );
```

With *writer* is created using *cvCreateVideoWriter*, and the video is created when I call *cvReleaseVideoWriter(&writer)*

The problem is I can not release memory allocated by *cvWriteFrame* until *cvReleaseVideoWriter* is called. That makes a big issue when I need record a long time video.

How can I handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the best solution in your case  (if you don't want to modify OpenCV code), is to write several video files.

As I can suppose, each frame is grabbed to RAM as is without any compressing. So, you can calculate a number of frames before amount of allocated memory exceed a particular size. Then you finish writing to file  and start a new one.